# How to solve integrand that diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-integrals

In the following Eq. 1, the integral diverges. However, it is part of my equation for the Expectation of rate and it should not diverge. I will really appreciate any help as I am stuck on this for over 4 days now.

$$\begin{align}
E = \int_r^\infty\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{1+ \mathrm{e}^{b-cx}}dx \tag{1} \label{1}
\end{align} $$

In the following, I found I can solve it using the **My Take** below, but even that diverges.

---

**My Take:**

--> following the properly $(1+z)^{-1} =  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1}(z)^{j-1}$

$$E = \int_r^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-x}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1}(e^{b-cx})^{j-1}dx$$

$$E = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1} e^{b(j-1)}\int_r^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-x}.e^{-cx(j-1)} dx$$

$$E = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1} e^{b(j-1)}\int_r^\infty\mathrm e^{-x-cx(j-1)}dx$$

$E$ diverge even now.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I guess $c \ge 0$. Why do you say that equation $(1)$ diverges? $e^{-x}$ tends to $0$ rapidly

Comment: all other constants are positive i.e. $r,b,c \geq 0$

Comment: Please see the edit now observe that as $j \to \infty$, the $e^{\infty}$ will also reach to infinity

Comment: This may mean that your method is not valid. It doesn't mean that the original integral diverges.

Comment: you can easily do this integral by u substitution.. at a glance --  $\int du u/(1+u)$ with $u = \exp(b-cx)$

Comment: @kevinkayaks Easily? According to *Mathematica* $$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{b-c x}+1} \, dx=\frac{e^{(c-1) x-b}}{c-1}-\frac{e^{-x} \left(-e^{c x-b}\right)^{1/c} B_{-e^{c x-b}}\left(2-\frac{1}{c},0\right)}{c}$$

Comment: Yup, you're right @Raffaele! Thanks. My glance is not correct : )
The result is a beta function with the wrong integration limit though... (not a logarithm, as my glance above). So the mathematica result indeed makes sense !

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $b,c>0$ we have
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{b-c x}}=\frac{1}{e^x+e^{b+(1-c) x}}<\frac{1}{e^b\left(e^{x-b}+e^{x-cx}\right)}<\frac{1}{ke^{x}};\;k>0$$
Therefore the integral converges for the comparison test.